# AttributeError("'set' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
message = "fancy message here that needs utf encoding".encode('utf-8')
await channel.send({messages}.decode('utf-8'))
```

Then i get error:

```
exception=AttributeError("'set' object has no attribute 'decode'")
```

If I try to drop the decode utf-8 in the channel.send the message that gets sent has a bunch of \xe2\x8a\ and other weird encoding in it (And it dosen't display my fancy characters), Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: *{messages}* is a set containing one item - i.e., the reference to your string. That's probably not what you wanted

Comment: Sorry that was a typo (the typo is not the actual issue), it's message in my code

Comment: So what error do you get now and what does your updated code look like?

Comment: The error is the same, the typo is only in this stackoverflow post

Comment: I don't understand. If you've removed the braces then you no longer have a set. So why would you get an error related to a set when there isn't one? Please show your updated code and full stack trace if you still want help

Answer (score -1):

your'e inserting your encoded message into a set when u use the curly braces and set has to decode attribute as the error says.
to decode the string when sending it you can do something like this:

```
channel.send(f"{messages.decode('utf-8')}")
```

or alternatively and even better as @JCaeser mentioned you can just use `channel.send(messages.decode('utf-8'))` if all you need is the messages content to be sent.

Comment: Why use an f-string here when *channel.send(messages.decode('utf-8'))* will suffice?